# How to retrieve a post through the json rest API without showing it on the web site?

Tags: json, wordpress, rest, api, post

The json REST API is included in WordPress from version 4.7 (http://v2.wp-api.org). I am using the Wordpress json REST API as a backend for an Android app. All Wordpress posts are published on my Wordpress website. Some posts must exclusively be included in the REST API for use in the Android app, but not published on the website.

Is it possible to get a post through the json rest API but not show it on the web site?

Comment: One option is placing the posts in a special category (e.g. 'AppOnly') and exclude this category from the Wordpress 'main loop'. Like here: https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Exclude_Posts_From_Some_Category. These posts are still included in the json REST API.